# Scraping with cefsharp

Tags: c#, web-scraping, webbrowser-control, cefsharp

I have a problem I want to scraping with CefSharp, with what statement can I insert data into an input type = text in its property "value" and how can I get the contents of a table, all this using CefSharp

I have scraping with webbrowser native of .net but in the page that I want to realize the data collection when I load the page this hangs my program and closes it, the solution I found is to change the browser and use CefSharp since it does the task without problems, but now I do not know how to get the data, much less insert.

The code that I use with webbroser is the following

Insert information

```
foreach (HtmlElement etiqueta in webInterno.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("input");
                    if (etiqueta.GetAttribute("name").Contains("strCurp"))
                    {
                        etiqueta.SetAttribute("value", txtCurp.Text);
                    }    
                }
```

Get information

```
webInterno.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("input");
                        if (etiqueta.GetAttribute("name").Contains("strCurp"))
                        {
                            Info = etiqueta.InnerText;
                        }    
                    }
```

this same thing that I do with the webbrowser control as I can do with cefSharp??

Thanks

Comment: You access the `DOM` using `javascript`. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#javascript-integration

Comment: Rewrite your code as `javascript` and execute or evaluate it. evaluate being return a value.